# Checking negative diagonal for connect 4 game in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I am in the process of creating a game of connect 4 in python (trying to learn python). The check for row, column and +ve diagonal seem to work however, I am struggling with negative diagonal. I cannot wrap my head around the indexing needed to check for it.

I am fully aware the code I have is by no means complete – I am simply ensuring the check function works before moving on and improving it…

The full code I have is:

```
board = [[' ' for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]

def check_win(game_board, player):
    """
    Check if a player has won the game of Connect 4 on the given game board.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    game_board: list of lists
        The game board represented as a matrix of characters. Each element of the matrix represents a cell on the board,
        which can be empty (' '), or occupied by a player ('X' or 'O').
    player: str
        The player to check for a win. Must be either 'X' or 'O'.

    Returns:
    --------
    bool
    """

    rows = len(game_board)
    columns = len(game_board[0])

    for row in range(rows-3):  # Nested loops iterate over whole board
        for col in range(columns - 3):

            check_row = [game_board[row][col + j] for j in range(4) if 0 <= col + j < columns]
            check_col = [game_board[row + j][col] for j in range(4) if 0 <= row + j < rows]
            check_posit_diag = [game_board[row + j][col + j] for j in range(4) if 0 <= row + j < rows and 0 <= col + j < columns]
            check_negat_diag = [game_board[row + j][col - j] for j in range(4) if 0 <= row + j < rows and 0 <= col - j < columns]

            for list in [check_row, check_col, check_posit_diag, check_negat_diag]: # Checks if the list has 4 of the same characters
                if list == 4*[player]:
                    print("You have 4 in a row")
                    return True

    return False


board[3][4] = board[2][5] = board[1][6] = board[0][7] = "X"

check_win(board, "X")
```

When I call my function, I would expect to have the message "You have 4 in a row" printed to console but nothing gets printed – namely because my check does not work.
Any help to sort this out would be greatly appreciated, also, if you have any recommendations on what I should improve for legibility, that would also be appreciated.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Try some debugging with print functions of the various check_* variables, to see what's going on. As well as `print(row, col)` for each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things in your logic needs to change, because fundamentally:

#### The range of starting points to consider, varies for the 4 types of direction

- When you are testing for 4 in a row horizontally, you need to try starting in *columns* 0 to n-3 (exclusive), as you are doing, but need to test *every row*. This is because even rows n-3, n-2 and n-1 are valid places where 4 in a horizontal row are a win.

Here are the valid starting points (`*`) for an 8x8 grid. Invalid starting points are shown as `.`.

```
*****...
*****...
*****...
*****...
*****...
*****...
*****...
*****...
```

- Similarly, when testing for 4 in a column vertically, you need to test *every column*.

```
********
********
********
********
********
........
........
........
```

#### For diagonals, you have a double restriction.

- For the down-and-to-the-right diagonals, you are right to consider rows 0 to n-3 (exclusive) and columns 0 to n-3 (exclusive).

```
*****...
*****...
*****...
*****...
*****...
........
........
........
```

- However for the down and to the left diagonals, the range of acceptable starting points is *displaced to the right*.

```
...*****
...*****
...*****
...*****
...*****
........
........
........
```

#### This would be easier to code without errors with separate loops the four directions

That way, you can be explicit each time in your mind's eye, as to which set of 4 cells you are checking.

#### To compact your code, you could squash down to two loops

The "straight" up/down and left/right loops are testing a the smae *number* of starting points (5x8 or 8x5), while the diagonals are testing a *different number* of starting points (5x5).

The two loops might be

```
for i_long in range(8):
    for i_short in range(8-3):
        
        test for a horizontal run, starting from i_long down, i_short across
        test for a vertica run,    starting from i_short down, i_long across

for i1 in range (8-3):
    for i2 in range (8-3):
         test for a diagonal(+ & +) run from (i1,i2)
         test for a diagonal(+ & -) run from (i1,8-i2)
```

#### Your code is failing to do that for negative diagonals

You are testing, with `col` ranging from 0 to 4 (inclusive), not from 5 to 8 inclusive:

```
check_negat_diag = [
    game_board[row + j][col - j] 
    for j in range(4) if 0 <= row + j < rows and 0 <= col - j < columns
]
```

If you want a quick fix for your existing program, try this:

```
check_negat_diag = [
    game_board[row + j][3+col - j] 
    for j in range(4) if 0 <= row + j < rows and 0 <= 3+col - j < columns
]
```